# Delphi - memory leak in TSevenZipVCL

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, 7zip

testing for memory leaks with madhi's madExcept, and the component TSevenZipVCL (http://www.rg-software.de) it's reporting a leak here:

```
  POleStr = PWideChar;
  TBStr = POleStr;
    function TSevenZip.List: Integer;
    ...
      for i := 0 to w - 1 do
      begin
        name := new( TBSTR ); <-------
        ptype := 0;
        inA.GetPropertyInfo( i, name, prop, pType );
```

even if I add Dispose(name) the leak occurs, what could be wrong?

TSevenZip unit posted here: http://pastebin.com/bhvERDJv

Comment: You need to show more detail. What is the interface, and what is the protocol of the function call? Don't do this blind? You must understand what the code is doing. I'd guess that the call to New is bogus. But cannot be sure.

Comment: Posted the full unit to http://pastebin.com/bhvERDJv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
inA.GetPropertyInfo( i, name, prop, pType );
```

This function appears to be passed an index in the first parameter, and the returns the information for the property with that index through the other parameters. The `IInArchive` interface has been very poorly translated by whoever wrote the code that you are calling. The function looks like this:

```
function GetPropertyInfo( index: DWORD; var name: TBSTR; var propID: PROPID; 
    var varType: {PVARTYPE}Integer ): Integer; stdcall;
```

The C++ declaration looks like this:

```
STDMETHOD(GetPropertyInfo)(UInt32 index, BSTR *name, PROPID *propID, VARTYPE *varType);
```

The `name` parameter is a COM BSTR that is allocated in the function, and returned to the caller.

I would declare it like this:

```
function GetPropertyInfo( index: DWORD; out name: WideString; var propID: PROPID; 
    var varType: {PVARTYPE}Integer ): Integer; stdcall;
```

By doing this you will ensure that the compiler is able to deallocate the COM BSTR when you've done with it.

You should remove the call to `New`. It is completely spurious.

Comment: Thanks that works. Only the BTMemoryModule leak remains now from the other question where you also posted on.